# issue when ssh-ing to EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I am getting the following error:

```
sudo ssh -i -v ~/.ssh/shopious.pem ubuntu@54.245.124.178

dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
Warning: Identity file -v not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname /Users/myusername/.ssh/shopious.pem: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

How is this possible? I am not sure what I changed, but before it was working using the same exact command.

Answer (score 3):

You have your command line wrong

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/shopious.pem ubuntu@54.245.124.178
```

should work.

- -v Verbose mode
- -i identity file - selects a file from which the identity ... is read.

You are telling ssh to use a file called `-v` as the identity file and to connect to host `~/.ssh/shopious.pem`. You really should take a look at the [ssh man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201)

Comment: now I am getting this: https://gist.github.com/3423268

Comment: @lain have you check my gist?

Comment: @user79356: That's a different problem to the one you asked about above and if you search SF you'll find plenty of similar questions to look at.

Comment: I have scourged all over SF without any luck